# Can I achieve this auto-height, paneled layout in CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I need to have this kind of layout for an app I'm writing, but after three days on it I can't get it working. Can I achieve this layout without using tables or jQuery?

[image]

This almost works, only the the middle panel pushes the footer off screen

```css
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#container {
    background-color: #666666;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
#top {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #999999;
    height: 120px;
    width: 100vw;
}
#side1 {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
#footer {
    display: block;
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">top</div>
    <div id="side1">side</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be kind and share your efforts

Comment: You have to decide, it's either *tables* or *flexboxes*. Share your code, tell me your choice and I'll help you.

Comment: I know how to do it with tables, but it fails miserably when using divs :) I need the most clean, codeless, simple solution. If tables are ok, then tables, if flex, then flex, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with flex box by setting the autofit sections to `flex-grow: 1;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header,footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}
section aside {
  width: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}
section main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<section>
  <aside>aside</aside>
  <main>main</main>
  <aside>aside</aside>
</section>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: That worked, but what about the middle row columns, as in the graphic?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.

Comment: Spoke too soon: in Chrome, the vertical panels go all the way down behind the footer!

Comment: @AramAlvarez I'm on chrome and that isn't happening for me. Do you have to put content in them or anything to trigger it, or are you seeing that with my snippet here?

Answer (score 0):

You can you use Viewpoert Height and calc function in css. 
check this http://jsbin.com/lodoxetuku/edit?html,css,output

```
.top{
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  text-align:center;
}
.bottom{
  height:100px;
  background:green;
  text-align:center;
}
.middle{
  height:calc(100vh - 220px);
  background:yellow;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope i got your question right.

If you can make it be positioned absolutely, and set height to 100%, it will fit the closest relative parent, and the body if none.